# How is it possible to view windows environment variable without executing arguments within it?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Basically I would like to export my exact `PATH` variable to a file automatically. It contains things like `%ANT_HOME%/bin` and I would like to keep it that way. From what I could find, using both set and echo will execute that argument and give me the absolute path. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a copy of your PATH *without* expansion of environment variables you could save the following as "rawPath.vbs"...

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh
Set wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Wscript.Echo wsh.RegRead("HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path")
```

...and then issue the following command to pipe the output to a file

```
cscript -nologo rawPath.vbs > myPath.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you see `%ANT_HOME%` when you execute SET from the prompt?

If so,

```
>filename echo %path%
```

should export the path as desired.

If the PATH variable does not actually contain the "%" characters, then it's already been resolved. And remember, "%" is actually a legitimate (but annoying) filename character...

You CAN set a "%" character into an environment variable

```
set var=%%something%%
```

will set var to `%something%`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `%` good sir, example

```
>echo %path%
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\system32\wbem

>echo ^%path^%
%path%
```